# Conflict error on installing phpmyadmin on centos 7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos7

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin after upgrading my php 5.4 to php 7.2 (using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7)).

But I get this error:

```
Error: php72u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64
```

Longer version of error:

```
--> Processing Conflict: php72u-common-7.2.11-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.2.11-1.ius.centos7
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php72u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've removed everything from old php as running `yum list installed | grep php` shows nothing from older version:

```
mod_php72u.x86_64                      7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
php72u-cli.x86_64                      7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
php72u-common.x86_64                   7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
php72u-fpm.x86_64                      7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
php72u-fpm-nginx.noarch                7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
php72u-mysqlnd.x86_64                  7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
php72u-pdo.x86_64                      7.2.11-1.ius.centos7            @ius
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to restart?

Comment: @Lithilion Yupe! just did. didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who may have the same problem, I solved the issue by installing `phpMyAdmin` using specific php version:

```
yum install phpMyAdmin php72u-{json,tidy,process,cli,bcmath}
```